# Linear transformation analysis...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't know if what I've concluded is right, that's the reason for this post.

I have:
$$
f:R^n\rightarrow R^n\\
B_d \text{ basis for my domain}\\
B_i \text{ basis for my image}\\
$$
By definition of a linear transformation, I can affirm that $B_i$ is the vectors of $B_d$ transformed, right?

So if I have $dim(ker(f))=s$, by rank-nullity theorem, I'll have $dim(im(f))=n-s$.

Having a bases for my kernel, since by definition it's going to be all vectors in my domain, that when transformed take me to the $0$ vector in my image, I can guarantee that the basis of the kernel is some number of L.I vectors that are in $B_d$ correct?

Assuming that what I've concluded is correct, if I expand some $n-s$ L.I vectors to the vectors that I already have (basis for kernel), I'll get $B_d$. If I apply these vectors that I've added to the transformation, am I going to get the basis of my image?! By the first definition, my intiution says that I'm correct... But I really don't know...

Thanks.

Comment: "By definition....right?" No...and I've already this three times and I still can't understand what you have. Why don't you write the whole problem from the beginning? Your $\;B_d\;$ is a basis with $\;n\;$ vectors, and $\;i\le n\;$ But for that who knows what's going on.

Comment: What can't you get?! Everything is clear! $B_d$ is a basis for my domain, and $B_i$ is a basis for my image.  Both have $n$ L.I vectors... What's going on?

Comment: I don't write the whole problem because it isn't a problem. It's something that I think I've concluded, but I need someone with more knowledge to see if it's correct!

Comment: Ok, so it is clear if you say it is.

Comment: Thanks. Can u please check if that's correct?!

Comment: @Br No, I can't because for that I'd have to understand what is going on, and I don't.

Comment: @DonAntonio What can't u get?

Comment: (1) You have, apparently, a linear map $\;f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n\;$ . Both linear spaces are of dimension $\;n\;$ , and to say that "the basis for your image", i.e. for Im$\,f=f(\Bbb R^n)\;$, is $\;n\;$ automatically makes $\;f\;$ surjective and thus bijective. Is this **really** what you meant? (2) If *really* $\;B_i\;$ is the basis of  Im$\,f\;$ then yes: $\;B_i\;$ is the image of $\;B_d\;$ under $\;f\;$ . (3) Why $\;\dim\ker f=s\;$ if we already have that $\;f\;$ is an isomorphism and thus $\;\dim\ker f=0\;$ ?

Comment: You're right. If it's an isomorphism I don't even need to evidence the dim of the kernel, because it's going to be $0$. So what I've concluded works for an isomorphism correct?! if it's not an isomorphism, and I have a linear map $f: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ with $m\neq n$ what I've concluded would be applicable?!

Answer (score 0):

The last comment was already too long so I'd rather do it here. Ok, so in the first case we have an isomorphism $\;f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n\;$, but the answer to your question is **no**: it is, in general, *not true* that  from a given basis you can always choose some l.i. vectors to be a basis of some given subspace.

For example, consider

$$f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;f\binom xy:=x-y . \;\text{The kernel here is}\;\left\{\binom xx\,/\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}=\text{Span}\,\left\{\,\binom 11\,\right\}\subset\Bbb R^2\;$$

but if you choose, or are given, the standard basis $\;\left\{\binom10\;,\;\;\binom01\right\}\;$ of the plane, you can't choose a subset of this basis to be a basis of the above kernel...

If the map is an isomorphism, as in your example, then the claim is almost trivially true, as since $\;\ker f=\{0\}\;$ and $\;\emptyset\;$ is **the unique** basis of the trivial subspace, and of course: the empty space is always a subset of any set...but **still** it contains no l.i. vectors from one given basis!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, $B_d$ is an arbitrary basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $B_i$ is an arbitrary basis of $\operatorname{im}f$. If that’s the case, then you cannot conclude that $B_i$ consists of the images of the elements of $B_d$. You can’t even conclude that the images of the $B_d$ vectors form a basis for the image of $f$: Although they do span $\operatorname{im}f$, if $f$ doesn’t have full rank (i.e., has non-trivial kernel), then $\dim\operatorname{im}f\lt\#B_d$, so you have too many vectors for a basis.

Neither can you conclude that some subset of an arbitrary basis $B_d$ will form a basis for $\ker f$. For a counterexample, consider the transformation given by the matrix $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$ relative to the standard basis. Its kernel consists of scalar multiples of $(1,-1)^T$, but clearly neither of the standard basis vectors spans this space.

Here’s what you can do, however. Let $r=\operatorname{rank}f$. Start with a basis $v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$ for $\ker f$ and extend it to a complete basis $v_1,\dots,v_r,v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$ for all of $\mathbb R^n$. Then the vectors $w_i=f(v_i)$ for $i\le r$ form a basis for $\operatorname{im}f$.